# How to set the entry point for a jar in command line

Tags: java, cmd

I have two class files HelloViewer.class and HelloComponent.class. I want to make it so when you run the jar it uses HelloViewer.class as the entry point. At the moment im using.

```
jar cfe Hello.jar main HelloViewer.class *.class
```

and i have also tried

```
jar cfe Hello.jar HelloViewer.class HelloViewer.class HelloComponent.class
```

i'm rather confused by this.

Comment: The syntax is `jar cfe [jar-name] [entry-point] [files to include]`. In your case: `jar cfe Hello.jar HelloViewer *`

Answer (score 1):

Canonical answer is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Briefly:

Make a file Manifest.txt

Give it the content `Main-Class: HelloViewer` (note that this should be the fully-qualified name of the class).

Then tell `jar` that it's the manifest by using the `m` argument:

```
jar cfm Hello.jar Manifest.txt *.class
```

Comment: You can instruct `jar` to build the manifest for you by specifying the entry-point with `e`

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'd be easier.